# Tooltip for Anonymous feedback shows "click again to undo" but can't really be undone

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, post-feedback

[image: click againto undo]

If you hover over the upvote/downvote buttons **on any website on which you don't have an account**, the tooltip will explain the action but with  the text

> (click again to undo)

Which is very confusing. Undo what?

I've checked with Firebug, there seem to be only one Ajax request, which is when the button is clicked, but when you click it again, nothing happens. So nothing is undone.

[image: no ajax]

**Is this a mistake in the tooltip? A bug in the Ajax request script? Or is it by design?**

Comment: The tooltip "doesn't know" you are not logged in, it's the same in both cases. In my opinion the "click again to undo" should indeed be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heh, that text has been there for so long, we've all forgotten about it :)

After the next build (> rev 2013.5.17.1019), anonymous users will no longer see the undo prompt on the tooltip.

Comment: Finally! Someone answered and cleaned up the "conversation". Thanks! (As a side note: It looks bad that officials aren't answering legitimate bug-tagged questions without a bounty).

Comment: @Adnan Bounty is a five letter word: bribe.

Comment: Not sure that it looks bad per se.  It's not like people farm rep on meta (I hope??), and certainly not devs/moderators.  I assume bounty is used on Meta as a short-cut to a "high priority" list.

Comment: The bounty just surfaced it to me (I'm on bug duty this week) and it was an extremely easy bug to fix.

Comment: @Adnan I spend thousands of rep on bounties here on Meta and 90% are for nothing, if not more. It's just a way to bump things up. Jarrod I knew this one was easy, hence only 50 lol! ;)

Comment: Oh, don't forget to status-complete the question. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh no, please don't get me wrong, I'm not even remotely suggesting that what attracted the attention is the rep gain itself. What I meant was if we have to use bounties to bring attention to **bug reports**, then something is clearly wrong here. Notice that it's been 2 weeks, score of 21, lots of comments, all without an official reply. It's a bug report (yes, it's a silly bug), and ignoring bug reports makes the users feel ignored themselves. Uses who feel ignored won't feel as much inclined to report future bugs.

Comment: @Adnan I understand but there are currently 3448 [open bug reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-reproduced+-status-review) and the number is only going up. We can't expect the team (or the one dev on bug hunting watch) to go through them all.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: You can successfully bribe with unicorn dollars?  Egad, they're more valuable than I thought.

Comment: Off topic question: did you by any chance touch the comment submitting system? I see the button becomes disabled now and looks like there's no loading indicator anymore when editing comment.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd no, not at all - could be you're having similar issues to [this user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181069/why-can-i-suddenly-not-able-to-comment-any-more)

Comment: No, I can add or edit comments just fine but I can swear the comment submit button didn't use to become disabled before and now it is. Can you just take a quick peek in the codebase to see if I'm just being paranoid?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hmm, I don't see anything; if it happens again, please check if there are any JavaScript errors happening!