# Why am I suddenly not able to comment any more?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

Today, I am having problems commenting on some questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

When I click *"add comment"*, I'm not getting a response. I also checked my own profile, try to see the graph of reputation, trying to figure out whether it is because of my own system setting or website error. I'm not seeing the usual graph.

Meanwhile, usually, if I put the mouse under my username, it will show a summary of my reputation, votes cast, etc. Now if I put the mouse under my username of SO, it does not respond.

Why this is the case? Anyone experienced similar situation like me?

I'm using Google Chrome. I tried to log out, clear all cookies and passwords, logged in again, using IE to test, same problems exist.

Comment: I see nothing unusual on your profile. What browser are you using? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers or other devices? This is more likely specific to your browser or device than to your account.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I am.

Comment: Log out and log back in again.  If that doesn't work, clear your cache and cookies, and try again.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I tried with IE and logged in, same thing happened. cannot comment

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK. do it now and will update with you, thanks!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried to log out all accounts, cleared the cookie, now logged in again, same thing happened. I am puzzled.

Comment: Are you logged into [this account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1760345/), or a different one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I logged in to that account, I don't have other accounts. I used the same Google account to login to all SE websites.

Comment: How much reputation does it say you have at the very top of the page?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It reads  "8300"

Comment: Which post are you trying to comment on?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Any one of them did not work. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656601/combining-the-values-of-two-vectors

Comment: Do other parts of the system work? Flagging dialog? Voting buttons? Close Vote button? It sounds very much like a JavaScript error rather than anything else. Does the network tab of Chrome (F12) show any errors in the JavaScript files loaded? Does the console tab of Chrome report any JavaScript parse errors? That fact it doesn't work in IE could mean something upstream has cached an invalid version of Stack Overflow's JS file(s).

Comment: @Matt there are other parts not function well. When I press F12, it does show 1 error.

Comment: ... which is what? Work with us here...

Comment: @Matt sorry. Here is the error: full.js:167 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( "

Comment: Yeah, most likely an upstream cache is screwing you over. Not really a lot you can do (unless you fancy contacting your network tech team/ ISP support, and ask them to clear the file from the cache); and absolutely nothing Stack Exchange can do if it's the case. Caches usually expire within a few hours, so you should be good after then.

Comment: @Matt thanks a lot. I will wait and try again later.

Comment: @taocp did this issue resolve itself?

Comment: @BenCollins Somehow it goes away, I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

The behavior on this one seemed to resolve itself and we didn't reproduce it, so marking this one accordingly.

Comment: Testing comments. Please bear with me.

Comment: Testing again. Sorry.